# Get Number from two uints

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, math, numbers, integer

I'm reading a signed 64 bit integer (Java `long`) from the network in Flash+ActionScript3, and storing it as two `uint`'s (first and last 32 bits).

```
var l:LongNumber = new LongNumber();
l.msb = socket.readUnsignedInt();
l.lsb = socket.readUnsignedInt();
```

How can I convert it into the actual number as a `Number`?

I'm aware `Number` can contain only 53 bit integers, not 64, but it's enough (though being able to throw an `Error` when converting larger numbers would be nice).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, **readDouble()** is useless here, it will interpret your 64 bit integer as an IEEE 754 formatted double-precision float (sign bit + 11 exponent bits + 52 fraction bits) and that will get you a garbage result.

**(Number(msb) * Math.pow(2, 32)) + Number(lsb)** isn't a complete solution if you need to support negative numbers. This code only gets the correct result if your number is zero or a positive number no greater than 2^63-1 (such that the sign bit is not set). If the sign bit is set, your code will effectively be interpreting the 64 bits as an unsigned integer, which is not what Java is sending you. If you're using your solution and wondering why you're always getting a positive result, this is why.

There is probably some really cool bit trick to support negative and positive numbers in one line of code, but because I can't work that out right now, I'll tell you the straight-forward way I see the solution in my mind:

I would use **msb & 0x80000000** to read sign bit. If it's not set, use your formula above. If it is set, convert your number from 2's complement format to unsigned format first:

**msb = (msb ^ 0xFFFFFFFF);**

**lsb = (lsb ^ 0xFFFFFFFF) + 1;**

Then apply your forumla to the msb and lsb and (because the sign bit was set) multiply the resulting Number by -1.

```
if (msb & 0x80000000)
{
    msb ^= 0xFFFFFFFF;
    lsb ^= 0xFFFFFFFF;
    result = -(Number(msb)*4294967296 + Number(lsb) + 1);
}
else
{
    result = Number(msb)*4294967296 + Number(lsb);
}
```

Comment: I'm actually not using negative numbers, even though the number is signed, but good to know for if I ever do.

Comment: Just a heads up, I removed the sign bit zeroing step in my calculation that was part of my thought process, but not part of the actual calculation--this happens automatically as part of the XORing. If you have a negative int, all you need to do is flip all the bits and add one to get the 2's complement, which gives you the absolute value of your negative number when put through your forumla, which you then multiply by -1 to get the actual value.

Answer (score 1):

I found my own solution (only for positive numbers)

`(Number(msb) * Math.pow(2, 32)) + Number(lsb)`

or hardcoding 2^32

`(Number(msb) * 4294967296) + Number(lsb)`

Answer (score 0):

[`readDouble()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/Socket.html#readDouble%28%29)
**upd:**

```
var ba:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
ba.writeUnsignedInt(uint1);
ba.writeUnsignedInt(uint2);
ba.position = 0;
result = ba.readDouble();
```

Comment: If I do `(msb << 32) + lsb` it simply becomes `msb + lsb`. `readDouble` reads from a floating point format, not an integer.